# open some link when my wifi connected in my iPhone mobile

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, wifi, http-redirect

We need when wifi connected in iPhone mobile.We need open app-story in browser automatically.i.e We have 4 wifi's Himansu,hits,poll,hotspot.We  need When wifi  connect Humans after connected it's redirect to below link

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8

Please give me any idea.First tell me it's possible or not

Answer (score 4):

Using the code apple provide [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/index.html)

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reach startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8"]];

}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8"]];
}
```

**getting Wifi network Name**

**Step 1:**

import the framework `#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>`

**Step -2**

```
implement the method in 

     CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    CFDictionaryRef myDict =   CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));

   NSLog(@"Connected at:%@",myDict);
   NSDictionary *myDictionary = (__bridge_transfer   NSDictionary*)myDict;

   NSString *  SSID = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"SSID"];
   NSLog(@"bssid is %@", SSID);

  // your console output is just like 
   SSID = "Eqra'aOrange";
```

**Step - 3**

```
  now you check your condition 

    if ([SSID isEqualToString:@"Himansu"])
    {
      // customize your code
     }
    else
     {
     // do your stuff
    }
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karithik thanks for reply. Please give me some clarity like my iPhone have himansu wifi so we need to show alert or redirect to some page .if other networks no need to redirect other pages

Comment: check the updated code and thing that were u need to add this and optimize the work